# remove old brass tap

Tags: taps

I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to remove this type of tap in my bathroom. It is leaking and it gets worse and worse everyday so I'd thought of replacing the washer.

[image]

What are the next steps?

Answer (score 1):

> **What are the next steps?**

I don't know all of them but I suspect they start with

- lift the handle off the splined shaft (it may be very stiff)
- look for a locking nut that secures the valve mechanism into the body of the faucet

  - this may be hidden under a brass skirt that can be lifted when the handle is out of the way
- lift out, or unscrew the valve mechanism
- remove the washer from the bottom of the mechanism - it may be held in place by a screw.

Comment: Thank you for the steps RedGrittyBrick, I am still stuck at step one, I can't remove the tap handle, I tried spraying wd40 but no success lifting the handle off..